# Categorizing a person if at least one of his courses return a specific value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Context: The person takes several classes, and his ID and courses taken are stored in distinct rows in Oracle database.

Main objective: I want to see if a person has taken at least one of several classes, then label him 'Yes", and if not 'No'.

My simplified code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID AS Person_ID,
(CASE WHEN CLASS_TAKEN IN ('A','B','C') 
        THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'No'
    END) AS Mark
FROM classes_taken_table
Group By
ID,
CLASS_TAKEN
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Issue: The code works in most cases EXCEPT when person takes both class A and D. Two rows are now generated for the same person in the output, one with 'Yes' and the other with 'No' in the Mark column.

I want to take out the 'No' row for the person if he already has a 'Yes' row.

I tried Max function but couldn't get the 2 rows to merge. It seems simple but can't get around it. :(

Comment: What if a person took first D and A ? Do we need to show this person also ?

Comment: Yeah. Order doesn't matter in this scenario. So in your case that person would still have one row where Mark column= 'Yes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of `MAX` function

```
SELECT
    id AS person_id,
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN class_taken IN(
                'A','B','C'
            ) THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END
    ) AS mark
FROM classes_taken_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

However, this makes use of the fact that string 'Yes' is "greater" than 'No.

You can avoid that with `COUNT`

```
SELECT
    id AS person_id,
    CASE
            WHEN COUNT(
                CASE
                    WHEN class_taken IN(
                        'A','B','C'
                    ) THEN 1
                END
            ) >= 1 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END
    AS mark
FROM classes_taken_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87a07/15) ( Thanks @Bob Jarvis for the data set)

Comment: if you use MAX then do you need distinct?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used the MAX function but also has the classes in the GROUP BY clause. Taking it out worked.

Comment: second query will return expected output?

Comment: I'm assuming also that it should be >=1 THEN 'YES' instead of >1 THEN 'YES'

Comment: @Gaj : Thanks for noticing, I had copy pasted it from question.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You can use the following:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, MAX(MARK)
  FROM (SELECT ID AS PERSON_ID,
               CASE WHEN CLASS_TAKEN IN ('A','B','C') 
                 THEN 'Yes' 
                 ELSE 'No'
               END AS Mark
          FROM CLASSES_TAKEN_TABLE)
  GROUP BY PERSON_ID
  ORDER BY PERSON_ID
```

This counts on the fact that 'Yes' will sort after 'No.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87a07/11)

Best of luck.

Comment: do we need inline view? please don't make the query complex